# AWS policy principal with service and account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have the policy attached to role in AWS.

```
            "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
                "Version": "2012-11-17",
                "Statement": [
                    {
                        "Sid": "",
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Principal": {
                            "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
                            "AWS": [
                                "arn:aws:iam::123:root",
                            ]
                        },
                        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
                    }
                ]
            }
```

So this policy has 2 types: of principals aws account and aws service.

The thing I didn't find in the docs, do these principals go together or overlap?

Is it ec2 + all users of 123 account, or only ec2 services from 123 account?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible for an EC2 instance to assume a role directly from another account. You can instead allow an EC2 instance's role to assume another role from with in the EC2 instance. In this case, you can assume the role using aws-sdk or cli.

- Assign a role to the EC2, attach a policy to the role allowing the role to assume the role

  ```
   {
       "Version": "2012-10-17",
       "Statement": [
           {
               "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
               "Resource": "*"
           }
       ]
   }
  ```
- In the destination Account, create an IAM role with a trust relationship allowing the source role to assume.

  ```
   {
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Statement": [
       {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": {
           "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::012345678901:root"
         },
         "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
       }
     ]
   }
  ```
- Access the destination role from the instance using the assume role api call.
  aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/xaccounts3access --role-session-name s3-access-example

Comment: Thank you for the info, but you didn't answer my question. The piece of code I'm posted is simplified. It works in production now, so I don't need the advice how to make it work.  According to what you said that ec2 can't assume the role from another account, it means that my posted code means: all users of 123 account and ec2 services of current account?